# How do I pass the git branch name to an IntelliJ maven build?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I've recently started using IntelliJ Idea, after years of Eclipse usage.

One feature I am missing is the environment variables available via eGit for run commands that Eclipse has.

For example, in Eclipse, I can pass arguments to Maven, which reference git values like so:

`-DgitBranch=${git_branch}`

Then I can use this in Maven for whatever I need via filters.

I realise I can use a maven plugin to populate this in the build step, however that doesn't work in our CI server, because `.git/` is not always available to the build.

How can I get the branch (and other git meta-data) passed into Maven when clicking the little green triangle in IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't see how CI could be a limiting factor regarding using a Maven plugin, as you could just have the plugin installed locally and run it through a Maven goal configuration. Or use profiles to separate CI behaviour from local behaviour.

Comment: Seems there is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155840